# How to set default page in power BI Embedded report

Tags: javascript, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

I'm using a power-bi Embedded report in my webpage.The report have multiple pages.
I need to set the default page based on drop-down selection.Is there any query-string parameter i can use for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways to do so with the [Power BI JavaScript API](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript).

You can change the settings in the [embed configuration](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embed-Configuration-Details#options) object and set the default page by specifying the page name.

```
var embedConfig = {
  ...
  pageName: 'ReportSection3'
};
```

You can also use the [setPage](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/classes/_src_report_.report.html#setpage) method to set the active page of the report.

```
report.setPage("page2")
 .catch(error => { ... });
```

---

EDIT:

You can also add `&pageName=YourPageName` to the embed URL to set the default page, i.e. `https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&pageName=YourPageName`

Comment: Sorry i think i didnt get that .. I'm directly refering the powerBI in a Iframe in my MVC .cshtml page ( <iframe width="xx" height="yyy" src="https://msit.powerbi.com/view?r=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>. Could you please explain how I can implement on this.Thanks

Comment: @CGN007 That's the Power BI JavaScript library which allows your application more interaction with the IFrame. You can check the code and live demo [here](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/code-demo/index.html). I've also added an alternative solution above which uses the query string. Hope it works for you.